# Is showing 1 reputation for a suspended user too harsh?

Tags: discussion, account-suspension

When a user applies for a job and links his/her Stack Overflow profile and in case he is suspended, it just shows 1 reputation which really makes a bad first impression and could be a hindrance in his/her growth.

Reputation is not mere points; they show user participation and knowledge sharing by writing either questions or answers. It is due to my Stack Overflow profile that I got a job in my first interview.

Apart from suspension due to voting irregularity, why not show reputation and show the suspension message to the user only?

Answer (score 23):

If my account would be suspended, I would be smarter than link to it in my application. On the other hand, if somebody submitted an application for a position at the company I work for, I consider it a **gift** that I can see if that person is suspended or not; it's something I'd **definitely** like to discuss during a job interview.

Stack Exchange isn't that different from a real life job; not only your knowledge matters, but also the way you apply and teach it, and if you play by the rules or not.